# How do I clone a repository on a local Gitlab server from another computer on the network?

Tags: git, networking, ssh, server, gitlab

As the title says, I'm trying to clone a repository (named devops) that exists on a local Gitlab server from another computer on my network.

My setup is as follows:

- I have a Mac that is running an Ubuntu Server OS via VirtualBox (named gitlab-server).  This is where I have Gitlab configured and working properly, as I am able to access the repo on the Host-only Adapter from other VirtualBox operating systems via SSH.
- On the same network I have another computer using Ubuntu that I am trying to configure to be my deployment server (let's call this deployment-server).
- On the deployment-server, I have added the following line to the `/etc/hosts` file:

  - `192.168.1.20 gitlab.test`
  - That is the IP address to the gitlab-server
- Currently, I am able to SSH into the gitlab-server from the deployment-server via the NAT network configured by VirtualBox.  I set up port forwarding from external port 2222 to internal port 22.

  - I run `ssh -p2222 jaded@gitlab.test` to access gitlab-server
- An SSH key from deployment-server has been added to the Maintainer's profile (jadedInsomnia89) for the project in GitLab.

However, when I run `git clone git@gitlab.test:jadedInsomnia89/devops.git` on the deployment-server, I get the following error:

> Cloning into 'devops'...
> ssh: connect to host gitlab.test port 22: Connection refused.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

How do I properly access the GitLab server on the gitlab-server OS?  Please let me know any other details you may need.

**Note:**  I am setting up another computer for the deployment-server because the Mac doesn't have enough RAM to simultaneously run a deployment server, Jenkins server, and a GitLab server on 3 separate virtual operating systems like the course I am currently attending does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your port number.

Try this:

```
git clone ssh://git@gitlab.test:2222/jadedInsomnia89/devops.git
```